# Int' is not convertible to 'Range<Int>

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a dictionary containing four images to set one of them as background of the `UIView`. The image selected will depend on the value of a `rand` number.

Here is code that creates a dictionary:

```
let backgroundDict = [
        "Clouds":   UIImage(named: "clouds.jpg"),
        "Clouds2":  UIImage(named: "clouds2.jpg"),
        "Sunset":   UIImage(named: "sunset.jpg"),
        "Sunset2":  UIImage(named: "sunset2.jpg")
    ]
```

Here is how I create the `rand` number:

```
var randNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(backgroundDict.count)))
```

This is the code that declares an array with the keys of the dictionary:

```
let backgroundArray = Array(backgroundDict.keys)
```

I get the error `'Int' is not convertible to 'Range<Int>` when I try to set the background image:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: backgroundDict[backgroundArray[randNumber] as String])
```

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 similar problems:

- the `UIImage` initializer is failable, so it returns an optional
- the dictionary always returns an optional when accessing an element by key

There are 2 ways to fix it:

- force unwrapping the image twice:

  ```
  UIColor(patternImage: backgroundDict[backgroundArray[randNumber] as String]!!)
                                                                             ^^
  ```
- force unwrap images when creating the dictionary:

  ```
  let backgroundDict = [
      "Clouds":   UIImage(named: "clouds.jpg")!,
      "Clouds2":  UIImage(named: "clouds2.jpg")!,
      "Sunset":   UIImage(named: "sunset.jpg")!,
      "Sunset2":  UIImage(named: "sunset2.jpg")!
  ]
  ```

  then use a single force unwrap when accessing the dictionary by value:

  ```
  UIColor(patternImage: backgroundDict[backgroundArray[randNumber] as String]!)
  ```

Although I'd usually recommend using optional binding to prevent runtime exceptions, I presume that in this case images must exist, and if they don't it is a development mistake (i.e. failing to add the images to the project or mistyping their names) - so an exception is a great way to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

`UIImage(named: "")` is an optional initializer `init?` and `UIColor(patternImage: ...)` takes a UIImage, so you need to unwrap your images before using them. You also need to unwrap the value returned from the dictionary:

```
//In Swift 1.2
if let optionalImage = backgroundDict[backgroundArray[randNumber] as String], image = optionalImage {
         UIImage(patternImage: image)
}

//In Swift 1.1
if let optionalImage = backgroundDict[backgroundArray[randNumber] as String] {  
     if let image = optionalImage {
         UIImage(patternImage: image)
     }
}
```

Comment: I would explicitly state that your solution requires swift 1.2

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries return optionals in swift to handle the case of non-existing keys. Using `if let image = backgroundDict[backgroundArray[randNumber]]` makes sure there's a corresponding UIImage for the key `backgroundArray[randNumber]` before assigning to the variable `image`.

The `image!` (optional unwrapping) inside the conditional is used because `image` is of type `UIImage?` (this will cause an error if it's nil). Initialising UIImage by name returns an optional to handle the case of not finding an image with the name provided.

```
let backgroundDict = [
            "Clouds":   UIImage(named: "clouds.jpg"),
            "Clouds2":  UIImage(named: "clouds2.jpg"),
            "Sunset":   UIImage(named: "sunset.jpg"),
            "Sunset2":  UIImage(named: "sunset2.jpg")
        ]

        var randNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(backgroundDict.count)))
        let backgroundArray = Array(backgroundDict.keys)

        if let image = backgroundDict[backgroundArray[randNumber]] {
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image!)
        }
```